# need help with mysql connection in php

Tags: mysql, mysql-select-db

I have a problem with mysql connection.

I have a php script which upload photo, this script do that:

```
1) mysql connection
2) check user rights for uploading photo (I use a sql query for this)
3) Image processing
4) sql query for insering photo data in database
```

I have set a mysql connection timeout to 5 s.

Everything works great if the image processing time is less than 5s (mysql connection timeout) otherwise I got a error when the step 4) is executed, the error is "Mysql server has gone away".

So, I checked if the mysql connection was still alive after the image processing and the mysql connection died if the image processing time is more then 5s.

I added this code after the image processing (step 3)

```
if(!mysql_ping($conn)){
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysqluser', 'mypass');
$db   = mysql_select_db('mydb',$conn);
}
```

but it doesn't work! this is my real problem.

```
var_dump($conn)
```

give a mysql ressource link but

```
mysql_select_db('mydb',$conn)
```

return FALSE, and

```
mysql_error()
```

return "mysql server has gone away"

Does anybody can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is your timeout 5 seconds?  increase that!

Comment: I don't need to increase the timeout, all my script doesn't need to keep a sql connection alive more than 5s. This is for handling the maximum mysql connection.

Comment: Er...if everything works fine when the processing time is less than five seconds, and doesn't when it takes longer, then I would respectfully suggest that Fosco is right and that's what you need to do.

Comment: Never use "urgent" (or even worse in uppercase) in the title or subject line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html:

> The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is that the server timed out and closed the connection.
>   [...]
>   Some other common reasons for the MySQL server has gone away error are:
>   * You (or the db administrator) has killed the running thread with a KILL statement or a mysqladmin kill command.
>   * You tried to run a query after closing the connection to the server. This indicates a logic error in the application that should be corrected.
>   * A client application running on a different host does not have the necessary privileges to connect to the MySQL server from that host.
>   * You got a timeout from the TCP/IP connection on the client side. This may happen if you have been using the commands: mysql_options(..., MYSQL_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT,...) or mysql_options(..., MYSQL_OPT_WRITE_TIMEOUT,...). In this case increasing the timeout may help solve the problem.
>   * You have encountered a timeout on the server side and the automatic reconnection in the client is disabled (the reconnect flag in the MYSQL structure is equal to 0).
>   * You are using a Windows client and the server had dropped the connection (probably because wait_timeout expired) before the command was issued.

etc.

Comment: I already read the mysql documentation. The problem is that the connection died if the image processing time is more than my mysql connection timeout. I know it. But why it doesn't work to connect me again to the mysql server. I found anything which could be the problem. I need help guys.

Answer (score 0):

first try increasing the timeout, then close the connection after step 4

`mysql_close()`

why increase the timeout? because the image processing definitely takes more than 5 secs, so this problem occurs!

Comment: increasing the timeout is not a good strategy, let's say I  have a limit of 256 clients for the mysql server. If 256 users upload photo and it takes 40s. the mysql server could not handle other connection during 40s. What I want is just reconnect me to the mysql server after the image processing. This is what I write in the php code but it doesn't work.